# KtLint: Function name should start with a lowercase letter for Composable Functions

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, ktlint

`Function name should start with a lowercase letter (except factory methods) and use camel case (cannot be auto-corrected)`

I am trying to disable this warning but the rule I'm trying is not working. Below is the code that I'm using.

```
id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint") version "12.0.3"

ktlint {
    version.set("1.1.0")
    debug.set(true)
    enableExperimentalRules.set(true)
    additionalEditorconfig.set(
        mapOf(
            "max_line_length" to "off",
            "ktlint_function_naming_ignore_when_annotated_with" to "Composable"
        ),
    )
}
```

Here is the link to the issue and library. [JLLeitschuh/ktlint-gradle/issues/736](https://github.com/JLLeitschuh/ktlint-gradle/issues/736)

Comment: try this 

> rulset

            ruleset("standard") {
            rule("function-name") {
                // This rule disables the warning for function names starting with a lowercase letter
                description = "Function names should start with a lowercase letter."
                configuration = ".*"
            }

Answer (score 4):

You can use the same rule from the `.ediConfig` file that you would add in the root of you project.
So just add a line:

```
ktlint_function_naming_ignore_when_annotated_with = Composable
```

Comment: Nope. Says property is not supported.

Comment: @NathanMDT Says so but it is still working

Comment: It was added here: https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint/issues/2259#issuecomment-1732333419

Comment: Configuration file should be named `.editorconfig`, not `.ediConfig`. See: pinterest.github.io/ktlint/0.49.1/rules/configuration-ktlint